# Combining Models that have already been finalized

Tags: modeling, modifiers

So I have made a model in blender such as eyes with reflections, a body with fur, a glossy beak and now I want to combine them but when I do, It makes everything have fur and removes their original textures! I have tried everything.

[image: The model]

Comment: Once you've combined everything, you need to edit the resulting mesh, select each of the original object's meshes and assign their materials to them one at a time.

Comment: ok thanks ill try that

Comment: How do i select the objects seperately if they are combined?

Comment: In edit mode, hover over part of the mesh from one of the original objects, and type L.  that is the shortcut for "island select".    Once you've done that enough times, stick it's material into a material slot, and hit 'assign' in the material panel of the properties editor.  Repeat as needed.

Comment: The fur can be limited by a vertex group/weight paint. Specify the vertex group as *Density* in the particle settings:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/cq1JR.jpg

Comment: After trying both of your solutions they worked except did not fix everything one of the eye is still covered in puff and the white hair is not there (I put the white hair using a rectangle and put hair on it). https://imgur.com/ivxm5CQ